# Prevent adding styles to cell contents stacking vertically?

Tags: html, css

I have a rows of cells with text in each cell. Given the example of one cell, if I add styles to individual words in the cell (lets say "testing one two three", I change to:)

```
<td class="cell">testing <p class="highlight1">1</p> <p class="highlight2">2</p> <a href="#">3</a></p></td>
```

The cell contents stacks vertically with testing, 1, and 2 on new lines

Comment: Do you want each one to be in its own table cell?

Comment: add `style="display:inline"` to your `<p>` tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `p` is a `block level` element, use `span` instead which is an `inline element` and it won't cause any breaks in your text, moreover it is used for this type of styling only.

If you are interested to refactor your code a bit..you can write this as

```
<td class="cell">
   testing 
   <span>1</span>
   <span>2</span> 
   <a href="#">3</a>
</td>
```

And not you can use `nth-of-type` CSS selector to apply styles to your span elements without calling classes like

```
.cell span:nth-of-type(1) {
   /* Targets 1st span element inside .cell */
}

.cell span:nth-of-type(2) {
   /* Targets 2nd span element inside .cell */
}

.cell a {
   /* Targets a element inside .cell */
}
```

> Note: Older versions of IE will have trouble with `nth-of-type()` so
>   use it wisely

Comment: thanks, now understand what spans for. Ill mark it once i can.